# Is there a way to edit the HTML of multiple SharePoint 2013 pages at once?

Tags: sharepoint

You guys gotta save me.
I'm supposed to go into 70+ SharePoint 2013 pages and manually replace each of the 3+ links in the html of each page with the correct copied version. As in, all the links currently point toward /place1/place2/link and now they need to be /place3/place4/link

So, there has got to be a way to mass edit all of the pages, like a find and replace, because otherwise I'm just going to go sit in a corner and cry for hours. I can't edit the folder structure because I'm not the project leader.

I will do whatever it takes to keep my sanity.

Comment: If the files are in the same (or a few) locations, you should copy them to your machine. If the pages are in a library you could use Explorer View to copy them. Then you run a script that changes the links. Now is a great time to learn PowerShell (assuming you're on Windows) and regular expressions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use powershell.
From [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29103/powershell-script-to-update-pages-dispose-page-afterwards):

```
function ProcessWeb($currentWeb)
{
    if([Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::IsPublishingWeb($currentWeb))
    {            
        $publishingWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($currentWeb)
        $publishingPages = $publishingWeb.GetPublishingPages()
        foreach ($publishingPage in $publishingPages)
        {
            if($publishingPage.ListItem.File.CheckOutStatus -eq "None")
            {
                UpdatePage -page $publishingPage
            }
        }    
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor red "FINISHED"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host -Foregroundcolor Red "^ not a publishing site" 
    }
}

function UpdatePage($page)
{
    $page.CheckOut();
    Write-Host -Foregroundcolor green $page.Url;        
    $NewPageContent = $page["PublishingPageContent"].Replace("/place1/place2/link","/place3/place4/link");
    $page["PublishingPageContent"] = $NewPageContent    
    $page.ListItem.Update();
    $page.CheckIn("nothing");
    $page.ListItem.File.Approve("Updated PublishingPageContent to replate place1/place2 with place3/place4");
}

ProcessWeb(Get-SPWeb -identity http://myintranet.com)
```

Note that you will need to work out how a good replace statement will work.
Also this automates changes that could go wrong, so make sure you do it first on a dev/uat environment before backing up the content database on production and then finally giving it a go.